# Triple integral - volume of the intersection of two balls

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral

We have the two balls

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$

and

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2z = 0$.

What is the volume of their common part?

[image: ddd001]

I am confused again. My book says $19\pi/12$.

Last night I got the same answer $19\pi/12$ and I was happy.
But upon a second thought, I think it doesn't make sense,
because the volume of a whole ball with radius $1$ is $16\pi/12$.
So there's no way the common part can be $19\pi/12$.

Now I redid the calculations and I am now getting $5\pi/12$.

What is the correct answer here?

How did I solve this?
Both balls have radius 1.
First I found the circle $L$ which is the intersection of the two balls. It is a circle with radius $\sqrt{3}/2$ in the plane $z=1/2$. Right?

Then I projected $L$ onto the $Oxy$ plane. Let's say this projection is the circle $R$, which of course also has radius $\sqrt{3}/2$.

OK, then using the equations of the two balls, the integral boils down to the double integral

$\iint_\limits{R} (z_2(x,y) - z_1(x,y)) \ dx \ dy$

which simplifies to

$\iint_\limits{R} (2\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} - 1 ) \ dx \ dy$

Then I switched this integral to polar coordinates $(\rho, \phi)$

$0 \le \rho \le \sqrt{3}/2$
$0 \le \phi \le 2\pi$

and I solved it.

And that's how I got $5\pi/12$

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, I am adding some detail.

Comment: Actually I think I have two identical spherical caps here with $h=1/2$ and $r=1$. So based on the formula written here (for $V$), I think my answer is correct:    
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap   Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your book is wrong and you are correct.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I have ever seen on this site.

Comment: @Gordon :) Is it true though? That's the only thing I care about. I can redo my calculations a few more times if needed, NP, I just want to know what the actual answer is.

Comment: @peter.petrov Yeah, I upvoted it.